# Create PDF from Flash CS6 (Client side)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, alivepdf, purepdf

I'm searching for a way to create a pdf file directly from flash 100% clientside.
I'm not able to interact with other files on the server (like using php for the pdf creation).

Can this be done with the purePDF / AlivePDF library directly in AS3?
I'm using Flash CS6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AlivePDF is an open-source ActionScript 3 (Flash, Flex, AIR) PDF generation library ported from the FPDF PHP project.
>   It allows you to generate PDF's 100% client-side.

http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/?page_id=2

I say yes :)

Comment: Yes but, but then I read this: "AlivePDF lets you create PDF from Flash in client-side, but sounds like you need a server-side solution, which can be done by calling a server-side script (eg. PHP)" [Link](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/776277)

Comment: what is this program being run from? I downloaded alivepdf and it looks like they use a tiny php script to just prompt the browser to save the file. Using Air you can use `Method.LOCAL` and it will save it without that php script. If wherever your program you're running has an internet connection, you can specify a remote URL to the PHP file.